# How to pasting the text without formatting lose in MS-Word2010 equation

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, equation-editor

I would like to convert the running text into Equation in MS-Word2010

For example I have already keyed the text "A<sup>2</sup> + B<sup>2</sup> = C<sup>2</sup>", and I have tried to copy and paste that text into MS-Word2010 equation editor. While doing so the superscript styles has been lose, it past like A2 + B2 = C2.

For detail I have added the screen capture here [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT5nj.png)

Even I have tried in VBA code, but it not worked. Here is the VBA code as I tried:

```
Sub Macro3()

Selection.CopyFormat
Selection.OMaths.Add Range:=Selection.Range
Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
ActiveDocument.Save
```

End Sub

Is there is any option to convert the normal text into equation without formatting lose? Or paste the text into equation editor window without formatting loses?

Comment: Have you right-clicked and tried all the different, special paste options that are there?

Comment: A I have tried but it's not worked!

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2010 you still can use the "old" field `eq`. This field is useable for easy equations and one can format it easy like the surrounding text. Your example would be

```
{ eq a\S(2) + b\S(2) = c\S(2) }
```

I would use this field only for small formulas, I want to use in flow text. For ambitious, big formulas, I would use the equation editor.

Comment: Yes, you were wright. But here my question is, already keyed text needs to be paste without formatting lose in equation.